# Automorphisms of Finite Field Extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $K \subset L$ finite (therefore algebraic) field extension. So not neccessary Galois. How to see that for automorphisms following inequility holds:

$$|Aut(L/K)|\le|L/K|$$?

Comment: Unless the extension is Galois, then it doesn't hold.

Comment: Inequality? Do you want to prove $|\text{Aut}(L/K)| \le [L:K]$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: This follows from the *linear independence of characters* lemma. Have you heard that phrase? Locally you can start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2082648/11619) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131892/11619). [Keith Conrad's blurb](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/linearchar.pdf) is most likely a better resource.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Linear independence of characters lemma says (if I found the correct one) that for any field $L$
and any group $G$ (here $G= L^*$), the ***set*** of homomorphisms from $L^*$ into the multiplicative group $L^*$ is linearly independent over $K$. 
I guess here your idea would be to show that the $K$-vector space $Aut_K(L,L)$ is finite dimensional? Or did I misunderstood your hint?

Comment: Linear independence says that $Aut(L/K)$ is linearly independent over $L$ as a a subset of the space of $K$-linear transformations from $L$ to $L$. If you meant the latter with $Aut_K(L,L)$ then, correct. As a vector space over $L$  $End_K(L,L)$ has dimension $[L:K]$ and the claim then follows from basic linear algebra.